# Reading multiple ultrasonic sensors with BBB using python

Tags: python, sensors, beagleboneblack

So i'm starting to use hc-sr04 ultrasonic sensors and ran into a problem. I want to read multiple sensors (two for starters) but I get the same distance value on both. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO
import time

def distanceMeasurement(TRIG,ECHO):

    GPIO.output(TRIG, True)
    time.sleep(0.00001)
    GPIO.output(TRIG, False)

    while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 0:
        pulseStart = time.time()
    while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 1:
        pulseEnd = time.time()

    pulseDuration = pulseEnd - pulseStart
    distance = pulseDuration * 17150
    distance = round(distance, 2)
    return distance

#Configuration
GPIO.setup("P9_15",GPIO.OUT) #Trigger
GPIO.setup("P9_12",GPIO.IN)  #Echo
GPIO.setup("P9_11",GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup("P9_13",GPIO.IN)

#Security
GPIO.output("P9_11", False)
GPIO.output("P9_15", False)
time.sleep(0.5)

#main Loop
try:
    while True:
       for i in range(2):
           if i == 0:
               recoveredDistance = distanceMeasurement("P9_11","P9_13")
               print "Distance1: ",recoveredDistance,"cm"
           elif i == 1:
               recoveredDIstance = distanceMeasurement("P9_15","P9_12")
               print "Distance2: ",recoveredDistance,"cm"
       time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Measurement stopped by user"
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

I get the same reading on both no matter the distance to the object on sensor2, the distance read in sensor1 is what both display; seems that sensor2 is ignored.

Doing some "manual debugging" (i.e. print TRIG, ECHO) I notice the function recives the correct parameters, here is the output to that "debugging":

```
P9_11
P9_13

Distance1:  20.79 cm
P9_15
P9_12

Distance2:  20.79 cm
P9_11
P9_13

Distance1:  20.13 cm
P9_15
P9_12
```

I want to use that one fucntion to read all the sensors. Thank you in advance

Comment: There's a simle typo in `recoveredDIstance`. Also the `for` / `if` / `else` does not make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You print the same result twice, because the second measurement is saved as `recoveredDIstance`. So `recoveredDistance` is unchanged. Python is case sensitive.

```
while True:
    recoveredDistance = distanceMeasurement("P9_11","P9_13")
    print "Distance1: ", recoveredDistance, "cm"
    recoveredDistance = distanceMeasurement("P9_15","P9_12")
    print "Distance2: ", recoveredDistance, "cm"
    time.sleep(1)
```